How to scrape element covered by another element in Selenium?
I'm trying to scrape some data, but div element I need is covered by an element with a link.
Website: https://www.euroleaguebasketball.net/en/euroleague/teams/alba-berlin/games/ber/?season=2023-24
When trying to use this code:
pts1 = []
pts2 = []

table = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//article[contains(@class,"game-card-view")]')
for match in table:
    pts1.append(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, './div/div[3]/div[1]/span').text)
    pts2.append(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, './div/div[3]/div[2]/span').text)

I get NoSuchElementException. There are no iframes and xpath is correct. Problem seems to be that the stuff I need is behind another element:
<article class="game-card-view">
    <a href="URL">
    <div>
        <div>
        <div>
        <div>
            <div>
                <span>
            <div>
                <span>

My guess is that  element is the reason why I can't scrape the data I need since it covers the whole div element. Is there a way to bypass that  element?

NoSuchElementException means that your locator is either wrong, there's a timing issue that you need to solve using WebDriverWait, or there's an IFRAME or shadow-root. This has nothing to do with one element overlapping another. Can you share a link to the page?

Please update the provided HTML in your question with actual, valid HTML.

Locator is not wrong, I checked in DevTools and all, I already tried adding time wait and there is no iframe or shadow-root

The problem is with these two lines,
pts1.append(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, './div/div[3]/div[1]/span').text)
pts2.append(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, './div/div[3]/div[2]/span').text)

You are intending to search from the table elements found in the line above, you even added the '.' at the start of the XPath but you forgot to change driver.find_element() to match.find_element().
The updated code would be
pts1 = []
pts2 = []

table = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//article[contains(@class,"game-card-view")]')
for match in table:
    pts1.append(match.find_element(By.XPATH, './div/div[3]/div[1]/span').text)
    pts2.append(match.find_element(By.XPATH, './div/div[3]/div[2]/span').text)

print(pts1)
print(pts2)

and it prints
['84', '83', '103', '85', '79', '82', '88', '71', '93', '66', '101', '89', '65', '63', '82', '68', '77', '67', '82', '74', '85', '89', '64', '102', '99', '89', '68', '85', '79', '85', '86', '87', '86', '80']
['75', '94', '68', '84', '86', '90', '71', '106', '77', '81', '87', '80', '82', '88', '76', '83', '71', '94', '91', '70', '71', '97', '62', '81', '75', '74', '73', '99', '71', '82', '75', '76', '91', '68']


Damn, such stupid mistake. Didn't use Selenium for a while, completely forgot how I did it before. Tnx for your help.

Nah... it's not stupid. A lot of people make that mistake.
